# How can I change the format of a file´s permissions?

Tags: c, permissions, formatting, format, ls

Well, I´m doing and ls program in C and I have a problem. I have to show the file permissions with this format:

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

But I get the permissions as a int because this return me this value as a int:

```
lstat(file->d_name, &info);
printf("%d \n", info.st_mode);
```

This shows for exemple: `$ 33188`

How can I convert the int permissions to `drwxr-xr-x`?

Thanks very much.

Regards.

Comment: AND that number with the proper masks to determine what is and is not possible and then generate codes accordingly.  If you're feeling lazy, you could just find the source code for `stat` and took a look at the code they use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mode of a file is a bitset of permissions and file type field. These flags are defined in [`man stat.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html).

You can extract the information from the mode like this:

```
switch(mode & S_IFMT) {
  case S_IFDIR:
    mode_text[0] = 'd';
    break;
  /* add other possibilities here */
  default:
    mode_text[0] = '-';
}
mode_text[1]= (mode & S_IRUSR) ? 'r' : '-';
mode_text[2]= (mode & S_IWUSR) ? 'w' : '-';
/* the third one is special; can indicates setuid as well */
mode_text[3]= (mode & S_IXUSR) ? (mode & S_ISUID) ? 's' : 'x' : '-';
```

etc. for group, others.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `chmod` describes the relationship between the two.

Comment: It might be worth adding that the system call chmod (2), rather than the utility program chmod (1) explains the meaning of the bits in thet permission value, and identifies the header file which contains the flags which are used to test for each permission value.

Comment: This is not a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `info coreutils ls` documentation tells you how `ls` decides how to translate the `st_mode` file mode bits. However for a basic implementation of `ls` you can just check each appropriate bit in turn and output the appropriate letter if it is set or `-` if it is not.